# From UTF-8 to UTF-8-BOM using aix command/script

Tags: utf-8, aix

My AIX server by default generates file in UTF-8 .. I need to convert UTF-8 file to UTF-8-BOM .. Please suggest unixAIX command/script

Comment: Why just not adding a BOM at beginning of the file, with your preferred method? -- Note: it is discouraged to add BOM to UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for responding ... my file is line sequential means each record starts from new line .. Do I need to add BOM before first record of file ? Or need to write first record with BOM data only?

Comment: BOM is valid and allowed only as first "character" (more then 1 bytes) of a file. The right encoder is decided at very beginning. Many programs do not like BOM on UTF-8 (see a lot of statistical programs and libraries), but some (mostly Microsoft one [as a complex transition to UTF-8]) prefers it (or they requires manual intervention of user). From your comments: you should test on the program which should read the file. We cannot guess [and I expect at maximum the BOM at very beginning of file]